# Leksah without main

Tags: haskell, leksah

Is there a way to program in Leksah without creating a main function/module, to test small functions and programns, for example? Can't I just creat a new module and use it?

Thank you

Comment: To test small functions you can simply use ghci

Comment: I like the features that Leksah offers, like continuous compilation

Comment: @black_dragon I'd say GHCi is pretty awful for that purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leksah is designed to get you to structure your whole major project correctly from the start. If you want to use it for a quick editor, recognise that's not what it's for, but you can make a workaround:

Make a new workspace and package called Scratch/Scratchpad/Temp, with just one module in it. Use it when you just want to mess around a bit, and clear it out when you're starting something else.

Comment: (Hugs/Winhugs also lets you test functions without explicitly doing `:r`, so you could use it with a small editor for rapid messing, but I can understand if you really want to stick with the IDE you know and love.)